# How exactly to get on multiple Xcode teams?

Tags: xcode

Say my developer account is x@y.com.  Imagine you have two clients.

It is, **in fact**, possible to be on two different development teams:

[image]

That's precisely what I see when I log in to developer.apple.com member center (i.e., after their recent 24 hour downtime :/ ).

How did I achieve that? I'm trying to do it again with a third client but it seems almost impossible. When I log in as the third company, and try to add "x@y.com", I just get the annoying message

[image]

There are many questions about that annoying message, here on SO and elsewhere, but with no resolution. How to achieve the image shown at top? How to add a third one .. for that matter how the heck was the second added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darn - the answer here is pretty simple.

The "third company" has to log in on developer.apple.com ...

**NOT on AITconnect** .. itunesconnect.apple.com

There's then a facility to invite a new member - make them "admin" - who is **already an Apple developer**. It then works fine - that dev gets an invite email, can then get the certs, and so on.

It's an interesting phenomenon that there are dozens of questions about this on the net, due to the AIT connect confusion: essentially the solution is that simple.  Hope it helps someone googling.